# Cartesian product between MySQL records

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have this request selection:

```
SELECT entry_id, value_id, level_id
FROM entries t1, levels t2
WHERE entry_id =  '1'
AND t2.level_id
IN (
   SELECT value_level_id
   FROM values
   WHERE value_id = t1.value_id
)
```

Results:

```
entry_id                |  value_id  |  level_id
1                       |  a         |  l1
1                       |  b         |  l1
1                       |  c         |  l2
1                       |  d         |  l2
...
```

I want to make a request to get Cartesian product of elements of l1 & l2 for the same entry like this:

```
Entry_id  |  product
1         |  a,c 
1         |  a,d 
1         |  b,c 
1         |  b,d
```

I have tried to make this with `CROSS JOIN` but no chance!

Is there a way to make a request (procedure) to get this Cartesian product in other (perfectly a view) table ?

Comment: You should go to SQLfiddle.com, create your tables, load them with data and then share the link, otherwise proposed solutions are only going to be guesses

Comment: @AgRizzo this is it (examples): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e129f
Try this request out: `SELECT entry_id, value_id, level_id FROM entries t1, mylevels t2 WHERE entry_id =  '1' AND t2.level_id IN (SELECT value_level_id FROM myvalues WHERE value_id = t1.value_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2524/8)  You need to add more data for testing.  I guessed at what your values could be.  I put in a view for readability.  If this does not work, you must give more examples of what the data could look like and how final result set would look.  The basic concept is to continually LEFT JOIN to itself for each potential level and the nested final column with the COALESCE and concatenation functions.

```
SELECT l1.entry_id
  ,l1.value_id AS l1_value
  ,l2.value_id AS l2_value
  ,l3.value_id AS l3_value
  ,l4.value_id AS l4_value
  ,l5.value_id AS l5_value
  ,CONCAT(l1.value_id, 
    COALESCE(CONCAT(',',l2.value_id,
                   COALESCE(CONCAT(',',l3.value_id,
                                  COALESCE(CONCAT(',',l4.value_id),
                                           COALESCE(CONCAT(',',l5.value_id),''),'')
                                  ),'')
                   ),'')) AS listvalue
FROM vw_entries_levels AS l1
LEFT JOIN vw_entries_levels AS l2
  ON l2.value_level_id = 'l2'
    AND l1.entry_id = l2.entry_id
LEFT JOIN vw_entries_levels AS l3
  ON l3.value_level_id = 'l3'
    AND l1.entry_id = l3.entry_id
LEFT JOIN vw_entries_levels AS l4
  ON l4.value_level_id = 'l4'
    AND l1.entry_id = l4.entry_id
LEFT JOIN vw_entries_levels AS l5
  ON l5.value_level_id = 'l5'
    AND l1.entry_id = l5.entry_id
WHERE l1.entry_id = '3'
  AND l1.value_level_id = 'l1'
ORDER BY listvalue
```

Comment: +1: It works, but i have more the 100000 records in listvalue so it takes time to be executed, is there any methode to work-around execution time ?

Comment: @Drwhite - Did you check to make sure you had indexes where needed? (Put  `EXPLAIN` in the front of the query to see how MySQL will execute it.)  Unfortunately, I am out of ideas.  Do you need this to be dynamically executed?  Maybe you could build a temporary holding table (i.e., a cache table) and repopulate it on a regular basis.

Comment: @Drwhite - I don't know if you can re-architect the underlying solution, but if you can, look into Nested Sets (http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)  See the section on retrieving single path.